# Print newlines in exception message

Tags: python, exception, printing

Why can this not print two lines to the screen?

```
raise KeyError('a\na')
```

(edit)

and why does it work with `ValueError`?

I need to be able to print out a bullet point list in an exception.

Comment: Have you considered printing your bullet pointed list to stderr before raising the exception? e.g. `print("my message\nhas line breaks", file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: Alternatively, you could use try/except to catch the exception and print in the except block before reraising it

Comment: It can be a long stack and the user might miss it. That’s why I want it at the end

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html and see if there's a way to customize the traceback; Exceptions have a `with_traceback` method, not that I have figured out how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to convert it to a string and split by newlines:

```
try:
    raise KeyError('a\na')
except KeyError as e:
    strw = str(e)[1:-1].split('\\n')
    for s in strw:
        print(s)
```

Looks like you have to use `\\n` as delimiter and the quotes should be discarded.

Comment: You should print to `file=sys.stderr` if you do it this way, as in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and became curious. It turns out the reason is documented in the source code: `KeyError` overrides `__str__` so that if it receives the empty string `''`, the user will not receive a confusing error message.

Quote [from the CPython 3.12 source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0325a8a8cdba6c091bcbbb3c995f3bf1d1217012/Objects/exceptions.c#L2605-L2612):

```c
/*
 *    KeyError extends LookupError
 */
static PyObject *
KeyError_str(PyBaseExceptionObject *self)
{
    /* If args is a tuple of exactly one item, apply repr to args[0].
       This is done so that e.g. the exception raised by {}[''] prints
         KeyError: ''
       rather than the confusing
         KeyError
       alone.  The downside is that if KeyError is raised with an explanatory
       string, that string will be displayed in quotes.  Too bad.
       If args is anything else, use the default BaseException__str__().
    */
    if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(self->args) == 1) {
        return PyObject_Repr(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(self->args, 0));
    }
    return BaseException_str(self);
}
```